# Shuffling Images in Python

Tags: python, shuffle, psychopy

Hello Stackoverflow community, I am having trouble with a bit of code using the shuffle function:

```
red_image =  'DDtest/210red.png'
green_image = 'DDtest/183green.png'
b = [red_image, green_image]
c = shuffle(b)
win = visual.Window(size=(1280, 800), fullscr=True, screen=0, monitor='testMonitor', color=[-1,-1,-1], colorSpace='rgb')

teststimulus = visual.ImageStim(win=win,
    image= c, mask=None,
    ori=0, pos=pos1, size=[0.5,0.5],
    color=[1,1,1], colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
    flipHoriz=False, flipVert=False,
    texRes=128, interpolate=True, depth=-1.0)

teststimulus.setAutoDraw(True)
win.flip()
event.waitKeys(keyList = ['space'])
```

What this program is supposed to do is shuffle the order of the picture is displayed. For whatever reason, when I do this it just displays a white block instead. I certain the problem is the shuffle function because it works fine is I try to display a static picture. Any advice as to what the problem might be? Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: You haven't included all the code, so I can't tell if you are using `random.shuffle` from the standard library; but if you are, and if what you want is to randomly pick one from a bunch of choices, then the function you're looking for is `random.choice`.

Comment: ... and if you want to shuffle multiple objects and don't like to do stuff in-place, you can use ``random.sample``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do feel that there a few things in Python that one has to get used to. One thing is that often objects are handled "in place". This is true for `shuffle` too. Actually, you would have been fine using `b`. Python just shuffles the list argument itself. So every time you call `shuffle(b)`, you'll get a random ordering of your two picture names in the `b` object (you can leave out the "c =" part).

Looking at your code, you then still have to pick one of the pictures for `ImageStim` because the list always stays the same size (two picture names, just randomly ordered after each call). So you would have to do something like `image=b[0]` (first name) or `image=b[1]` (second name).

I didn't check all the code, so I don't know whether it will run for sure.

Best,

Axel

Comment: Axel is correct on both counts. Also, you will find things faster if you just create the teststimulus object once and then update it as required with a new image (e.g. teststimulus.setImage(b[0]). (I'm assuming you'll eventually put this code in a loop and display more than one image.) Creating an object has a substantial overhead compared to just updating its properties.